# Combine Content Egg Search form with WordPress and Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How I can combine Content Egg Search form or make it search from WordPress posts and Woocommerce products as well.

What I want is

Content Egg + WordPress + Woocommerce Search form combined

Content Egg Search Form Here it is [Content egg Search Form](https://www.keywordrush.com/docs/content-egg/FrontendSearch.html)

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_attr(\ContentEgg\application\ProductSearchWidget::getSearchFormUri()); ?>">

      <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Product search...">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />

      <button type="submit">Search</button>

</form>
```

Woocommerce Search Form

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

WordPress Search Form

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>
```

All of these three search form result displayed on diff. search result pages

Content Egg shows on

> ce-product-search.php

and I'm using code like - which works prefect

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[content-egg module=Amazon template=grid]'); ?>
```

WooCommerce and WordPress uses diff. template as well.

Currently I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone have same question here is what I did to combine search result and get from diff. query type

First Create a Search-Result.php file that your search form redirect to.
As you can see I store search query to variable and get output according to it.

```
<?php
                        $s=get_search_query();
                        $args = array(
                        's' =>$s,
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'post_type' => 'product'
                        );
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $the_query->the_post();
                     ?>           
                  <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
```

Output type 2

```
<?php
                $news=get_search_query();
                $argsn = array(
                's' =>$news,
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'post_type' => 'post'
                );

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $argsn );
                    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();

the_title();

}?>
```

Output type 3

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[content-egg module=Amazon template=grid]'); ?>
```

This is simple solution fit to me currently I faced issue for many days.